# Why is setAlarmClock not working for me in my dialog fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, setalarmclock

I am trying to set an android alarm manager, alarmMgr?.setAlarmClock . I have the code towards the bottom in my recyclerview adapter. It works fine to set the alarm. But in my dialog fragment, the code toward the top, whenever I hit the button to close the dialog fragment and also set the alarm, it does not work. I do not get an error or anything. Is this a context issue where I am using the wrong context? Or anyone have any ideas?

```
        //the below in my dialog fragment will not set an internal alarm
        var alarmIntent: Intent
        var alarmPendingIntent: PendingIntent
        alarmIntent = Intent(rootView.context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        alarmIntent.putExtra("alarmTimeEntityId", 0)
        alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(rootView.context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        alarmPendingIntent = alarmPendingIntent.let { intent ->
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(rootView.context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        }
  

        var trig: AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo =
            AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.timeInMillis, alarmPendingIntent)
        alarmMgr?.setAlarmClock(
            trig,
            alarmPendingIntent
        )

    
        //below works to set alarm, is in recylerview adapter
      var alarmTimeEntity: AlarmTimeEntity
      var alarmIntent: Intent
      var alarmPendingIntent: PendingIntent   
      
       alarmIntent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
       alarmIntent.putExtra("alarmTimeEntityId", alarmTimeEntity.alarmTimeId)
       alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, alarmIntent, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        alarmPendingIntent = alarmPendingIntent.let { intent ->
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE 
 or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        }


        var trig: AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo =
            AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.timeInMillis, alarmPendingIntent)
        alarmMgr?.setAlarmClock(
            trig,
            alarmPendingIntent
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt properly intitalize the alarm manager object.
I had    private var alarmMgr: AlarmManager? = null to declare it. But I needed to also have alarmMgr = this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager at some point before setting the alarm to make it work! clutz move. I keep doing that. Its there if anyone else needs it!